# How best to implement itoa and atoi?

Tags: data-structures, type-conversion

C/C++ Library comes with two functions namely "itoa" and "atoi" - the former converts an integer value to a character array. The latter does the vice-versa for string of character array containing numerical value.  The numerical values in either function could be either a positive integer or negative one.

I implemented the functions as follows:-
**itoa function**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void my_itoa(int num, char* str) 
{
    bool isNeg=false;
    if(num < 0)
      isNeg = true;

    int idx = 0;
    do {
       int j = num % 10;
       j = j < 0 ? j * -1 : j ;
       str[idx++]=j+48;
       num=num/10;
    } while (num!=0);
    if(isNeg)
       str[idx++]='-';
    str[idx]='\0';

    std::reverse(str, str+idx);
}
```

**atoi function**

```
void my_atoi(char* str,int& i) 
{
  bool isNeg = false;
  if(*str == '-') {
    isNeg=true;
    str++;
  }
  i=0;
  while(*str!='\0') {
    i =i*10 + (*str - 48);
    str++;
  }
  if(isNeg) 
    i=i*-1;
}
```

**Driver Code**

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    my_itoa(-1234, str);
    std::cout << "Str =" << str << std::endl;
    int j=0;
    my_atoi(str,j);
    std::cout << "j= " << j << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to see how I could get a production quality code for them - as the performance of above is not really upto standard of standard library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about improving/optimizing working code and therefore belongs on [codereview.se] instead. This site is for questions about problems with non-working code or programmers tools issues.

Comment: Before reposting to CodeReview make sure the code is _correct_. You have `cout` without a namespace and without `using`. And make sure it is tagged correctly (as [tag:c++]).

Comment: I think this is probably also a case of a student seeking help with their homework without actually saying they're seeking help on their homework. If it wasn't a homework assignment, they'd either not be trying to re-implement these wheels, or they'd be naming the wheels differently.

Comment: @EdGrimm, I have plenty of industry experience but asked this as I got this asked at a interview. Asking here just from genuine curiousity. Don't know if mentioning this fact would have made any difference above.

Comment: @Amadan,  Sure I would post in code-review tool. Should I close this here? (and how ?)